# Excel-DNA, The displayed array is an array full of #VALUE!, how to resolve this

Tags: c#, arrays, excel-dna

I am trying to use `Excel-DNA` and `ArrayResizer` to display an `54x4` array in excel. I have set up a breakpoint at the return value in my `C#` code. and can see the return value is good.

```
{object[54, 4]}
[0, 0]: "000001"
[0, 1]: "One "
[0, 2]: 12
[0, 3]: "OK"
[1, 0]: "000002"
[1, 1]: "Two "
[1, 2]: 21
[1, 3]: "Ok"
[2, 0]: "000003"
[2, 1]: "3"
......
```

The displayed array on excel is in the right size, but is filled with `#VALUE!`
 [image]

May know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @iliketocode I dont really understand what you mean. my intention is to write an array formula, and let it display the returned array on excel.

Comment: First step is to check that your array result works right if you leave out the ArrayResizer call. I.e just return that array and enter as an array formula into the right size, with Ctr;+shift+Enter.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft Excel may display the #VALUE! error if your formula includes cells that contain different data types.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Correct-a-VALUE-error-cec24732-88fc-4b76-945c-32fd4e847573

My thought is that the cause is your array, which is of type `object` has both strings and integer types in it and this is confusing XL.  With the information provided, my recommendation is to convert all values in your source array to `string` type instead of using `object` type-

```
    Object[] objArr = {"a", "b", "c"};
    String[] strArr = Array.ConvertAll<Object, string>(objArr, x => x.ToString());
```

Comment: Yes, try ensuring the column datatype is the same type you are writing/returning.

Comment: That would cause another set of problems, namely Excel reporting that numbers are showing up as text...

Comment: I dont think that is a problem, as in their sample, https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Distribution/Samples/ArrayResizer.dna, they did show mixed type array example.

Comment: @tesla1060 is there any reason you aren't using the excel object libraries directly? (Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library)

Comment: @code4life I don't think that should be a problem, excel can text represent numbers.  you could always just keep the cells formatted as General to prevent the 'numbers showing up as text'   "error" (although it's more of a warning than an error...)

Comment: @iliketocode: look at this class: ` public class ArrayResizer : XlCall` this does what you need for presenting the final results....

Comment: @code4life you mean when it checks for sheet limits?  there are about 1.04 million rows and 14k columns in the sheet, so I am not sure if that is the issue either.. but then again, if it is some sort of library issue then I would revert back to my previous comment that OP should just use the microsoft excel object library instead if possible.